# Распечатать Excel файл C#

Tags: c#, wpf, interop, epplus

Программа WPF заполняет Excel файл и после нажатия кнопки "распечатать" печатает документ. Раньше использовала для заполнения Interop.Excel, раньше работало, но теперь выдает ошибку

> (System.InvalidCastException: 'Невозможно привести COM-объект типа "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ApplicationClass" к интерфейсному типу "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Application". Операция завершилась со сбоем, поскольку вызов QueryInterface COM-компонента для интерфейса с IID "{000208D5-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}" возвратил следующую ошибку: Ошибка при загрузке библиотеки. (Исключение из HRESULT: 0x80029C4A (TYPE_E_CANTLOADLIBRARY)).')

Теперь использую EPPLUS, но через него нельзя печатать. Другие библиотеки оставляют водный знак. Помогите найти способ распечатать файл без вызова PrintDialog по нажатию кнопки.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Excel.Application xlApp;
            Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook;
            xlApp = new Excel.Application();
            xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\\Users\\Shkwarkel\\Documents\\ExcelHelperFiles\\test5.xlsx");
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet ws = xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1) as Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet;
            string printerName = GetActivePrinter();
            if (printerName != "")
            {
                PrintExcelSheet(xlApp, ws, printerName);
            }
            xlWorkBook.Close(true, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
            xlApp.Quit();
        }

        private static string GetDefaultPrinterName()
        {
            string default_printer = "";

            foreach (string printer in PrinterSettings.InstalledPrinters)
            {
                if (new PrinterSettings() { PrinterName = printer }.IsDefaultPrinter)
                {
                    default_printer = printer;
                }
                else
                {
                    default_printer = null;
                }
            }

            return default_printer;
        }

        internal static string GetPort(string printerName)
        {
            var devices = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(@"Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Devices");
            try
            {

                foreach (string name in devices.GetValueNames())
                {
                    if (name == printerName)
                    {
                        var value = (String)devices.GetValue(name);
                        var port = Regex.Match(value, @"(,\w+:)", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase).Value;
                        port = port.Replace(",", "");
                        return port;
                    }
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                throw;
            }
            return "";
        }

        internal static string GetActivePrinter()
        {
            string printer = GetDefaultPrinterName();
            if (printer != "")
            {
                string port = GetPort(printer);
                if (port != "")
                    return printer + " (" + port + ")";
                else
                    return "";
            }
            else
                return "";
        }

        internal static void PrintExcelSheet(Excel.Application app, Excel.Worksheet sheet, String activePrinter)
        {
            try
            {
                app.ActivePrinter = activePrinter;
                sheet.PrintOutEx();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Print error:\r\n" + e.Message);
            }
        }
Измененный код:

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Excel._Application xlApp;
        Excel._Workbook xlWorkBook;
        xlApp = new Excel.Application();
        xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add("C:\\Users\\Shkwarkel\\Documents\\ExcelHelperFiles\\test6.xlsx");
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Worksheet ws = xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1) as Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Worksheet;
        string printerName = GetActivePrinter();
        if (printerName != "")
        {
            PrintExcelSheet(xlApp, ws, printerName);
        }
        xlWorkBook.Close(true, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
        xlApp.Quit();
    }
internal static void PrintExcelSheet(Excel._Application app, Excel._Worksheet sheet, String activePrinter)
    {
        try
        {
            app.ActivePrinter = activePrinter;
            sheet.PrintOutEx();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Print error:\r\n" + e.Message);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Раньше это когда? Что изменилось? "Раньше использовала для заполнения Interop.Excel, раньше работало, но теперь выдает ошибку".  Это не имеет отношения к представленному коду, так как в нём нет заполнения. А какую ошибку даёт представленный код и в каком месте? Какая версия Excel?

Comment: Версия Excel: Microsoft® Excel® для Microsoft 365 MSO (версия 2307 Сборка 16.0.16626.20086)

Comment: Раньше, это где-то пол года назад. В программе ничего не менялось с того момента и все работало. И где-то пару недель назад при печати стало выдавать такую ошибку. Ошибка происходит в строке: xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\\Users\\Shkwarkel\\Documents\\ExcelHelperFiles\\test5.xlsx"); В методе Button1_Click
Добавила заполнение, если это поможет. Документ так же не может открыться в той же строке, когда пытаемся открыть workbook

Comment: Так же выдает ту же ошибку

Comment: а файл который Вы пытаетесь открыть программно, открывается средствами excell? Пользователь создает новый файл или Вы заполняете *шаблон*? ошибка повторяется на машине разработчика? версия офиса не изменилась?

Comment: Заполняет шаблон. Да, с помощью Excel документ открывается. Нет, офис не обновляла до этого.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Получилось решить проблему переходом на nuget пакет EPPLUS и функция для печати документа:

```
void PrintExcelSheett(string filePath)
        {
            PrintDialog pd = new PrintDialog();
            pd.ShowDialog();
            ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo(@"C:\\Users\\Shkwarkel\\Documents\\ExcelHelperFiles\\test4.xlsx");
            info.Verb = "PrintTo";
            info.Arguments = "\"" + pd.PrintQueue.FullName + "\"";
            info.CreateNoWindow = true;
            info.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
            Process.Start(info);
        }
```

Comment: Тоже рабочий вариант, поздравляю!

Comment: Спасибо за помощь, вы помогли в некоторых вещах разобраться

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте использовать классы _Application, _Workbook и _Worksheet вместо Application, Workbook и Worksheet. (Вместо метода Open для открытия книги метод Add - может, не понадобится.)

У меня такой код

```
            Excel.Application oXL;
            Excel._Workbook oWB;
            Excel._Worksheet oSheet;
            try
            {
                oXL = new Excel.Application();
                oXL.Visible = true;
                oWB = oXL.Workbooks.Add("C:\\Users\\auser\\Documents\\tmplt.xltx");
                oSheet = (Excel._Worksheet)oWB.ActiveSheet;
...
```

работает на двух компьютерах, сборки Excel 2302 и 2307, 64-bit.

Библиотека "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\ADDINS\PowerPivot Excel Add-in\Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.dll".

Comment: Ошибка осталась та же.
Я добавила к вопросу измененный код, с классами _Application, _Workbook и _Worksheet.

Comment: Не вижу изменённый код

Comment: уже есть, под прошлым кодом

Comment: Ещё проверьте ссылку на библиотеку. Я использую "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\ADDINS\PowerPivot Excel Add-in\Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.dll". Там несколько библиотек, я методом проб и ошибок выбирал нужную.

Comment: а почему не используете nuget пакет Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel?

Comment: @Bald а зачем, если Excel установлен со всеми необходимыми библиотеками?

Comment: Да, и у меня на обоих компьютерах Excel 64-bit, это тоже может иметь значение. А приложения одно .NET6.0/x86, а другое FW4.8/anycpu.

Comment: Непонятно, откуда берётся ApplicationClass. Может, что-то с реестром? Попробуйте сделать Repair installation для Excel.

Comment: Пробовала, тоже не помогло. Из-за этого перешла на nuget пакет EPPLUS. Заполняет без проблем, но нету возможности распечатать документ. Может вы знаете как это можно сделать? Пробовала разные способы, но либо библиотеки оставляли водный знак, либо печатали пустой лист.

Comment: К сожалению, не знаю.

Comment: Вот это "Ошибка при загрузке библиотеки. (Исключение из HRESULT: 0x80029C4A (TYPE_E_CANTLOADLIBRARY))" может говорить об отсутствии какого-то компонента, используемого "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.dll". Как у вас ставится приложение на целевой компьютер? Проверьте там наличие всех файлов. Если у вас один из последних .NET, все файлы должны быть в одной папке, и от пакета "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.dll" тоже (ну, может и в подпапке).